# Jar produced with lein uberjar fails on NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: clojure, compojure, leiningen

I have a simple web app with this project.clj:

```
(defproject squirrel-money "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "Squirrel Money"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0"]
                 [compojure "0.5.3"]
                 [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "0.3.5"]
                 [hiccup "0.3.1"]
                 [postgresql "8.4-701.jdbc4"]
                 [clj-time "0.2.0-SNAPSHOT"]]
  :dev-dependencies [[lein-eclipse "1.0.0"]]
  :main squirrel-money.main
  :repl-init-script "src/squirrel_money/init_repl.clj")
```

My main looks like this:

```
(ns squirrel-money.main
  (:gen-class)
  (:use 
    [compojure.core]
    [ring.adapter.jetty])
  (:require 
    [compojure.route :as route]
    [squirrel-money.savings :as savings]))

(defn launch [routedef]
  (run-jetty routedef {:port 17080}))

(defroutes money-routes
  (GET "/savings" [] (savings/render))
  (route/not-found "Page not found"))

(defn -main [& args] (launch money-routes))
```

With REPL works just fine. However, when I generate a jar with `lein uberjar` and try to execute it as:

```
java -jar squirrel-money-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
```

It dies with this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: compojure/response/Renderable
    at squirrel_money.main$fn__1067.invoke(main.clj:18)
    at squirrel_money.main__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at squirrel_money.main__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:1578)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:399)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:381)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__4511.invoke(core.clj:4905)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:4904)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:409)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:365)
    at squirrel_money.main.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: compojure.response.Renderable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 13 more
```

What am I doing wrong? How to get it to work?

Not sure if that matters, but I noticed that inside the jar my files, clojure itself and Java libs are unpacked as .class files, while all clojure libs are present only as plain .clj files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a leinigen 1.4.0 bug. You might want to try creating an uberjar with leiningen 1.3.1.

**Edit**:

Leiningen 1.4.0 deletes non-project `.class` files to work around a Clojure bug (see [CLJ-322](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/clojure/tickets/322-enhance-aot-compilation-process-to-emit-classfiles-only-for-explicitly-specified-namespaces)). Apparently this behavior can sometimes cause problems.

You can keep leiningen 1.4.0 from deleting non-project `.class` files by setting `:keep-non-project-classes` to `true` in your `project.clj`.

See the related [leinigen issue](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues#issue/141) for more info.