# clojure-noir project with generated uberjar - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: clojure, leiningen, noir

Following http://www.webnoir.org/ instructions to create a new project - I ran lein uberwar - this generates a single (executable) jar - however it is not able to find the main class as mentioned in the manifest - no class file found.

The app runs run with "lein run".

Is the uberjar meant to be able to run this way (I expect it launches an embedded jetty?)

FYI [Jar produced with lein uberjar fails on NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354293/jar-produced-with-lein-uberjar-fails-on-noclassdeffounderror) is similar - but out of date (this is with a newer version of leiningen where that specific bug is fixed).

Comment: I couldn't find any mention of "uber", "war" or "jar" on the webnoir site. It only mentions installing lein-noir plugin and running it to create a new project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to add gen-class to server.clj

`(ns myproject.server ... (:gen-class))`

For example: 
I've just deployed using lein uberjar, and I have the following:

In my project.clj:

```
:main myproject.server
```

In my server.clj:

```
(ns myproject.server
  (:require [noir.server :as server]
    [myproject.views.common]
    [myproject.views.index])
  (:gen-class))

(server/load-views "src/myproject/views/")

(defn -main [& m]
  (let [mode (keyword (or (first m) :dev))
        port (Integer. (get (System/getenv) "PORT" "8080"))]
    (server/start port {:mode mode
                        :ns 'myproject})))
```

- require the views at the top
- gen-class
- load-views

Now it works fine to java -jar myproject-standalone.jar.