# Java JAR does not contain correct dependencies

Tags: java, mongodb, jar, leiningen, mongodb-java

I am attempting to create a uberjar of my java project with a dependency for the `mongodb-java-driver` found [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver) which includes the `com.mongodb.*` packages.

Currently I have tried using leiningen versions `2.0.0-preview4` and `1.7.1`, and mongodb-java-driver version `2.7.3`. My project.clj dependencies appear like so:

```
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.0"]
             [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0"]
             [org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver "2.7.3"]
             [org.apache.commons/commons-math3 "3.0"]
             ]
```

While running the command `lein clean && lein uberjar` I see the following output:

```
...
Including mongo-java-driver-2.7.3.jar
...
```

Upon executing the uberjar I recieve the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/DBObject
    at org.ianalexan.Topology.main(Topology.java:69)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.DBObject
    ...
```

Apparently, [previous versions of leiningen had a problem with deleting .class files at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354293/jar-produced-with-lein-uberjar-fails-on-noclassdeffounderror), I believe I am not using a version affected by this issue.

How can I create an uberjar that contains the com.mongodb.* dependencies?

Comment: I have also attempted to create a maven2 `m2-pom.xml` file and use maven, but am observing the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a problem with the packaging app!